# Split GCP costs among different people

Tags: google-cloud-platform, billing

I'm part of an open-source project which offers among many other things a free service. This service, although being free for our users, is deployed on GCP and a member of the project pays for all the related costs.

Would it be possible to split all the costs equally between the 3 admins of the project?

So far I tried:

- linking multiple billing accounts to a project, but realized you can only link one.
- link multiple payment methods to a shared billing account, but realized that only one can be the primary, all the others are backups.
- setting up a business billing account, but it requires a specific location and we three all live in different countries.

Thanks

Comment: Charge them 33.3%; the amount can be parsed from the invoice, likely an API, too.

Comment: How can I _charge_ them? Are you suggesting one person pays for everything on GCP and the other two send money to the one who paid?

Comment: Since you can only set up one payment method, you will manage payment collection.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @John Hanley, you can only set up one payment method. So in your use case, you will need to manage payment collection as we cannot add multiple billing accounts to a project.

In Google Cloud, you set up a Cloud Billing account and use it to define who pays for a given set of Google Cloud resources.

The [payment methods](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/concepts#billing_account_types) available for your self-serve (online) Cloud Billing account depend on your currency and country. In many countries, you can set up a credit card, debit card, or bank account as a primary payment method.

You can also set up a backup credit or debit card to act as a safety net; if your primary payment method fails, we'll charge your costs to your backup payment method. This ensures that your Google APIs and cloud services keep running. Note that you cannot set up a bank account as a backup payment method.

For more information about adding a backup payment method refer [Add a payment method](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/payment-methods#add_a_payment_method).